# Magento Api request foreach error

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, rest-api, php-7, array

I am trying to get attribute option Ids for a sku using this below api call.

```
http://localhost/rest/V1/configurable-products/sh8/options/all
```

**I used this curl request:**

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://localhost/rest/V1/configurable-products/sh8/options/all",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "postman-token: f1457b50-7a5e-4f08-d6ee-8e3b0aad21bd"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {

   echo $response;
    }
```

**I got this below response:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 26,
        "attribute_id": "145",
        "label": "size",
        "position": 1,
        "values": [
            {
                "value_index": 25
            },
            {
                "value_index": 27
            },
            {
                "value_index": 28
            },
            {
                "value_index": 29
            }
        ],
        "product_id": 161
    },
    {
        "id": 27,
        "attribute_id": "146",
        "label": "color",
        "position": 0,
        "values": [
            {
                "value_index": 30
            },
            {
                "value_index": 31
            },
            {
                "value_index": 32
            }
        ],
        "product_id": 161
    }
]
```

**But when I try to access this in foreach like**

```
 foreach ($response as  $value) {
       var_dump($value);
    }
```

I get this below error:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Answer (score 1):

It gives the error because response is in json you need to do

```
$response = json_decode($response);
```

before passing to foreach

**I hope this will help**

Comment: @Ramesh brother please mark my answer correct if it's resolve your issue. this question is still open for others it may also help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your **$response** result is in JSON format so **you have to decode it** in order to access data.

```
$data = json_decode($response);
```

And in your **foreach** do like this to get the value of the key **attribute_id:**

```
foreach ($data as $value){
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $value['attribute_id'];
}
```

Note: you can change the key to what you need to get